# Error with AWS cognito confirmSignUp function

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to allow a user to enter the confirmation code set via email for them to confirm their account here is my function

```
    const handleConfirmationSubmit = async () => {
    console.log(email)
    console.log(confirmationCode)
    try {
      // Confirm the user sign-up using AWS Amplify Auth
      let code = confirmationCode
      await confirmSignUp( email, code );
      // Handle successful confirmation
      console.log('User sign-up confirmed successfully');
      // Close the dialog
      handleSuccessDialogClose();
      // Perform any additional actions after successful confirmation
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error confirming sign-up:', error);
      // Handle confirmation error and display error message
      setError(error.message);
    }
    };
```

Here is the error I am receiving

`Error confirming sign-up: EmptyConfirmSignUpUsername: username is required to confirmSignUp`

I have tried to change the arguments within the function to this

`await confirmSignUp( {username: email, code: code });`

and the error changes to this

`index.js:86 Error confirming sign-up: EmptyConfirmSignUpCode: code is required to confirmSignUp`

I have also tried many other configurations, I have used this before in the first way I showed and its never been an issue.